# permanently change a :root .css variable with javascript (getting info for variable via input)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on an idea for this website i'm creating and the idea is to basically ask the user for a color input (#12345;) and once inputted the user submits the input and that will change the .css variable permanently across all pages. Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="adminpage-background">
        <h1>Input to change primary colors (header, footer, service borders)</h1>
        <input type="text" name="primaryChange" placeholder="#12345;">
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="changeColor" value="Submit">
        <br></br>
        <h1>Input to change border colors (background border colors)</h1>
        <input type="text" name="borderChange" placeholder="#12345;">
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="changeColor" value="Submit">
        <br></br>
        <h1>Input to change background colors (background color)</h1>
        <input type="text" name="backgroundChange" placeholder="#12345;">
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="changeColor" value="Submit">
        <br></br>
        <h1>Input to change primary text color</h1>
        <input type="text" name="primaryTextChange" placeholder="#12345;">
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="changeColor" value="Submit">
        <br></br>
        <h1>Input to change secondary text color</h1>
        <input type="text" name="secondaryTextChange" placeholder="#12345;">
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="changeColor" value="Submit">
        <br></br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --clr-text: white;
    --clr-secondary-text: yellow;
    --clr-primary: #098ef6;
    --clr-background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    --border-color: white;
    --clr-bg-border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    
    --ff-primary: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    --ff-global: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    
}
```

My plan is to click the submit button once given an input for a valid color and then that will go change the :root variable for that specific area of color.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't change your css variable inside your css file from outside, without rewriting or preprocessing your file (for example on the server side). But you can still change it's loaded value on the client side. Here I made example for your first heading text and submit button:

```js
const primaryInput = document.getElementById('primary-text-input');
const primaryBtn = document.getElementById('primary-text-btn');

primaryBtn.onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--clr-primary', primaryInput.value);
};
```

```css
:root { --clr-primary: #098ef6; }

.primary-text { color: var(--clr-primary); }
```

```html
<div class="adminpage-background">
  <h1 class="primary-text">Input to change primary colors (header, footer, service borders)</h1>
  <input id="primary-text-input" type="text" name="primaryChange" placeholder="#12345;">
    <button id="primary-text-btn">Apply</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rodiax mentions it's probably not possible to change the actual value in the css file.

However you can set a localStorage object and read it on page load, which would set the CSS variable again throughout the page, for every new page the user visits.

```
primaryBtn.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--clr-primary', primaryInput.value);
    localStorage.setItem('primary-color', primaryInput.value); 
};
```

```
window.onload = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('primary-color')) {
        document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--clr-primary', localStorage.getItem('primary-color'));
  }
}
```